# javascriptファイルダウンロード時のファイル名の指定について

Tags: javascript, node.js

現在以下の様な手段を使ってサーバからファイルをダウンロードしているのですが、
ファイル名が指定したものになりません、原因が分かる方いますでしょうか？

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'test.xml';
a.href = 'http/XXX/XXX/user?id=1234';
a.click();
```

サーバー側はnode.jsで作成されていてurlで指定されたものをデータベースにアクセスして取得してくれるようになっています。

この時ダウンロードされたファイルの内容などは正しいのですが、ファイル名だけが指定したものになってくれません、、、どうしてでしょうか？

Comment: 確認したブラウザと挙動についてもう少し詳細を記載できますでしょうか？

Comment: [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)属性はHTML5で追加されたもので、対応していない環境もある上にクロスドメインでは使えません。サーバー側をいじれるという場合であれば、[Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)というHTTPヘッダでattachmentのfilenameを指定できます。

Comment: ブラウザはchromeを使用し、UIとしてはただボタンだけがありそれをクリックするとファイルがダウンロードされるという簡易的なものになっています。　クリックをするとuser.xmlというファイルがダウンロードされ、ファイル内容は合っています。

Comment: また、ローカルpc内でサーバーを動かしていた為クロスドメインでは無いと思われますが、サーバー側の詳細は知らない為どうなっているのかはいまいち分かっていない状態です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クロスドメインの問題はありますが、受付先で許可して、こうすれば取得できますね。
既に回答がありますが、対応ブラウザもご確認ください。

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function work(){
    var val1 = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById('name').value;
    downloadXML(val1, val2);
}

/**
 * @param url       String
 * @param filename  String
 **/
function downloadXML(url, filename){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
          a = document.createElement('a'), file;
    
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        file = new Blob([this.response], { type : 'application/octet-stream' });
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="ダウンロード対象のURL" />
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="保存するファイル名" />
<button onclick="work()">download</download>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

[caniuseのDownload attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)によると

- Internet Explorer 11
- Safari 10
- iOS Safari 10.2
- Opera Mini

は`download`属性に未対応です。